# ImageView, selecting a certain part Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

My vision is this-- I have an image of a human body(like an anatomy chart), and I want the user to be able to click a certain part of it and be able to communicate the body part they have clicked on, as in translating it to text... I wonder if this could be possible, and how? Any sample code/redirection to a tutorial would be helpful, or maybe just a practical idea...

Comment: I think you're talking about ImageMap kind of a thing. I'm not sure how to do that though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple approach is just to add an ImageView to you layout. 
Override [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) in the activity to capture touches and then translate the coordinates to texts.

Comment: how would you get the specific x and y coordinates that the user clicked on(as in the body part, in my case)

Comment: Well, first of all take a look at the javadoc i linked to. You'll see that onTouchEvent is passed a [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) which have the methods getX(int) and getY(int). You can use 0 as argument for these methods, it's only important for multi-touch.